# change attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am using a plugin called mobify.js to help with my responsive images. However, to avoid blocking the javascript, the documentation suggests adding a ‘x’ to the image source so it would be displayed as `<img x-src="..." />`.

This does not render or work in IE 8 and below so I need a way of changing the image tag back to `<img src="..."'>` for IE 8 and below only.

So far I have tried the code below but IE is not recognizing it.

//sets the image source equal to the x-src 
`<script> element.setAttribute("src",element.getAttribute("x-src"));`

//removes x-src 
`element.removeAttribute("x-src"); <!--<![endif]-->`

the HTML is set to:
`<div class = "item">
<img x-src = "images/vh2.jpg" alt="Vinehouse Homepage" class="img-responsive">
</div>`

Comment: Looks like an issue with using the wrong type of quotes.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Please include HTML as well.

Comment: Addind to what Travis said, use only single or double quotes.

Comment: Really, those quotes are weird. Must be imported by copy-paste from the office editing program.

Comment: I have added more code which should be helpful.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe a silly question... but are you setting element to the actual element? with var element = getElementById('myElement') statement or something?

Comment: No, im not using get elementByID, im just accessing all image elements as they are.

Comment: But you are actually assigning a reference to element, right? Maybe like `var elements = getElementsByTagName('img'); then looping through them?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle out of it? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: try using "srcElement" property  instead of "src"

Comment: You could also try adding two src attributes to your tag. One would be `x-src` and the other one would be the standard `src`. Something like this: `<img x-src="..." src="..."/>` But i'm not quite sure if that would help, considering that you provided us with so little information and code.

Comment: Hi Doozerman, i tried the 2 <img src> options before, it works however, in all browsers other than IE, the image displays twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided more information in one of the comments, we know that doing something like this:

```
<img x-src="..." />
<img src="..." />
```

Is going to display only one image for IE, and two for other browsers.

In this situation, we can use **conditional comments**.

```
<img x-src="..."/>
<!--[if IE]>
<img src="..."/>
<![endif]-->
```

This will make that `<img src="..." />` will only appear for IE, preventing the image from displaying twice on other browsers.

If you want to the image to be displayed in specific versions of IE, just add the version number behind `if IE`. Example:

```
<img x-src="..."/>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<img src="..."/>
<![endif]-->
```

More on condition comments: [Conditional Comments of IE](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/cc2.shtml)

Comment: I dont know if this would work as I cant declare my img tag code above the ie conditional statement, since those images are within a slider, and need to be in the body.